# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure myProcedure, Line 30 [Batch Start Line 2]

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure, when I run it, I get this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure myProcedure, Line 30 [Batch Start Line 2]
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'

This is my code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProcedure
    @StartDate Date,
    @EndDate Date,
    @LicenseRequestID int,
    @CRNumber nvarchar(40),
    @StatusID int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @query nvarchar(4000)
    SET @query = 'SELECT LRM.StatusID,cast(CRI.CRNumber as nvarchar(40)) CRNumber ,CRI.NAMEAR     CompanyName,CRI.CityAR CityName,CRI.PhoneNumber,CRI.CreatedDate CRIDate,LRM.CreationDate    LicenseRequestDate,LRM.ID LicenseRequestID,O.UserName OwerName,O.Email,C.Message,SD.NAME STATUS from CR_Informations CRI
LEFT JOIN LicenseRequestMaster LRM ON LRM.CRNumber = CRI.CRNumber
LEFT JOIN [User] O ON O.ID = LRM.CRNUMBER
LEFT JOIN Comment C ON C.LicenseRequestID = LRM.ID AND O.ID = C.SenderID
INNER JOIN StatusDetail SD ON SD.StatusID = LRM.StatusID '+
(case when ((@LicenseRequestID  is null) and (@CRNumber is null) and (@StatusID  is null) )
then ''
else
   'where '+
   (case when @LicenseRequestID is not null
   then ' LRM.ID like '''+@LicenseRequestID +'%'''+
       (case when @CRNumber is not null then ' AND ' else '' end)
   else '' end)+
   (case when @CRNumber is not null
   then ' CRI.CRNumber like '''+@CRNumber+'%'''+
       (case when @StatusID is not null then ' AND ' else '' end)
   else '' end)+
   (case when @StatusID is not null
   then ' LRM.StatusID like '''+@StatusID +'%'''
   else '' end )
 end)

 EXEC sp_sqlexec @query
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't have 38 lines. Something seems missing. And by the way, all these parenthesis aren't needed.

Comment: still error ........

Comment: still only 32 lines ........

Comment: with spaces ... its 37 i remves spces now its 33 ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not `END`ing the procedure's block. Try:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProcedure
                 @StartDate Date,
                 ...
                 @StatusID int
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @query nvarchar(4000);
  SET @query = ...
  EXEC sp_sqlexec @query;
END;
```

Note the `END` at the end.

There are still some other problems though:

- The nesting of the `CASE` expression can possibly be simplified.
  You don't make sure that the inputs get properly escaped.
- You should use `sp_executesql` with parameters instead of concatenation.

But likely dynamic SQL isn't really necessary here anyway. Check:

```
SELECT lrm.statusid,
       FROM cr_informations cri
            LEFT JOIN ...
       WHERE (@LicenseRequestID IS NULL
               OR lrm.id LIKE @LicenseRequestID + '%')
             AND (@CRNumber IS NULL
                   OR cri.crnumber LIKE @CRNumber + '%')
             AND (@StatusID IS NULL
                   OR lrm.statusid LIKE @StatusID + '%');
```

That should do what you want without dynamic SQL.

The `LIKE` operations on integers are questionable though. You really want to include for example `12345` when an integer parameter is equal to `1`? You probably just want `=` for them.

Comment: stored producer work bt data and tables are not coming

Comment: getting this error now ....

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '%' to data typeint.